# Completely and entirely and absolutely disable multi-window on Android

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, multi-window

I have Galaxy Note 4, and this feature (multi-window) is really driving me crazy. I keep disabling it, and it keeps enabling itself after some time. I have Android Lollipop 5.1.1 and before 5.1.0, and both had the same problem.

How can I turn this feature off and never see it ever again?

Comment: @beeshyams it comes back... That's the problem.

Comment: @beeshyams No :( it still comes back!

Comment: @beeshyams knowing that a solution doesn't work is still important.